# Jquery unsupported pseudo: focusable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, focusable

I tried to run the following code :

```
focusables = container.find(":focusable"); where container is a div.
```

I get the error :

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: focusable
```

I am using jquery-1.9.1.What is the reason? Is there any other way to find all the focusable elements in a div?

Comment: are you using jquery ui as well?

Answer (score 15):

This seems not to be part of jQuery, but of jQuery UI:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/44b2180782df6ef3324789324fcf3f98b85784a0/ui/jquery.ui.core.js#L93

Update:
I've extracted this code into a small jquery "plugin", see:
https://gist.github.com/njam/7974250